# How to launch and share from google+ app if installed

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6, google-plus

I have just implemented sharing feature for google+ using google+ SDK.

I have just used similar code like here https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share#basic_sharing

When I try to share something, It launches the safari and shares. Everything is OK.

But,
I would like to launch the google+ app if installed. I could not find anything about it in docs.

Does anybody know URLScheme of google+ app? If yes which parameters can be used?
Is it officially supported by google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not currently possible.  But you can always request a feature like this in our Issue Tracker, which you can find at http://developers.google.com/+/support.

I also recommend reading the question linked in the comment above, as it does provide information about a more general use-case.